# Responsive (?) Grid System

Tags: jquery, html, css

Look to [this site](http://www.unitedpixelworkers.com/). As you can see, it uses a responsive grid system. The grid flow works perfectly on 1920x1080 screen size as well as 1024x768.

I want to do the same thing with my website but without success. I've already tried some frameworks (**responsivegridsystem.com**, **foundation.zurb.com** and **gumbyframework.com**) and no success again.

To be more specific, I have a "2 column" layout. The left column has fixed width and the right column houses several other columns.

Follow my layout in **1920x1080** (works perfectly):
[image: i.stack.imgur.com/sRBF6.jpg]

My layout in **1280x1024** (unwanted space):
[image: 1280x1024 layout]

And finally, my layout in **1024x768** (again I have the unwated space):
[image: 1024x768 layout]

Instead of "unwanted spaces", I want to centralize all the layout — like the site that I've passed before.

My HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="left-sidebar float-left">
  <div class="shopping-list">
     <div class="inside-padding-10">
        <div class="shopping-list-header">
           <h1>0</h1>
           <p>
              Produtos na sua lista de compras
           </p>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="shopping-list-body">
           <button>Calcular menores preços</button>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main float-right">
  <ul class="products-list section group">
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
   padding-right: 195px;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.main {
   margin: 0 -220px 0 auto;
   width: 100%;
}

.main-content .left-sidebar {
   width: 200px;
}

ul.products-list {
   width: 100%;
}

ul.products-list li {
   background-color: red;
   width: 14.6em;
   height: 300px;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
   float: left;
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Your reference site also has "unwanted" space as you resize. I am not sure that what you want to achieve is the work of any single framework - it is most likely custom coded to suit their needs.

Comment: Don't use negative margins, only if you REALLY need it. but 9 out of 10 you won't.

Comment: @Rafael he needs it considering his layout.

Comment: @Michael oh no he doesn't. We've been doing grids for over a decade now, we can do better than that kind of hackery. ;)

Comment: @Barney Outside of using javascript or flexbox which has virtually 0 support, and assuming the OP wants a a CSS only solution then yes, he does considering the foxed width of the sidebar.

Comment: @Michael the problem with the negative margin hack is that the 'fluid' column needs to be specifically aware of the widths of its siblings. Try using a modular grids system [like the one in OOCSS](http://oocss.org/grids_docs.html) instead. Flexbox support is confusingly forked, but [pretty wide nowadays](http://caniuse.com/flexbox). The OP requested emulating a site that performs dynamic box-fitting techniques using Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick play with the console reveals `$.fn.isotope` — [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html) is a jQuery plugin by [David de Sandro](http://desandro.com/) that allows block layouts to responsively rearrange (to various stimuli). A look at the DOM inspector reveals unexpected structure on the elements, but it still looks to be functionally probable.

**EDIT**: Just checked the DOM again — it is indeed Isotope: `$('[class*=isotope]').length>0 === true`

Comment: Awesome plugin, love it. He just needs to re-css the whole thing.

Comment: @Rafael he's actually working on a superseding project, [Packery](http://metafizzy.co/blog/packery-preview/)…

Comment: Hi, guys! I think Packery will be my solution, but until its launch, what is the best alternative? Isotope?

Comment: @Guillerme yes — that's what's used on the site you linked to.